# Using Authentication With a Custom Reader Monad With Servant

Tags: haskell, servant

An API protected with Basic Authentication

```
type SubApi = API1 :<|> API2 :<|> API3
type API = BasicAuth "foo-realm" AuthData :> SubApi
```

supports handlers of type `AuthData -> Handler a`.

I have a set of handlers:

```
handler1 :: Request1 -> AuthMonad Response
handler2 :: Request2 -> AuthMonad Response
```

That run in an AuthMonad, which is a ReaderT whose context is constructed in part from AuthData.
Using `enter` and `AuthMonad :~> Handler`, I can get a `Server API` supporting handlers of type `AuthData -> AuthMonad`, but what I'd really like to do is use the `AuthData` argument as the environment to runReaderT.

I don't quite grok enough of the type wizardry going on with `enter` to understand how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: It might be helpful if you included the actual declaration of `AuthMonad`. Also, what `enter` are you talking about? If you aren't going to provide its type, at least provide a link to the package that it is in.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned in the body in addition to the tags, this is a question specific to [haskell-servant](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant)

Comment: I second Kwarrtz: I think the question is hard to answer without more information about `AuthMonad`. It's difficult to write the `Nat`ural transformation required without knowing its definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized I left this one hanging.

Mostly, was just over-thinking this one -- the answer is pretty obvious.
In the above case I made a function that would create the natural transformation:

```
enterAuth :: AuthData -> AuthMonad :~> Handler
```

Which I then used when constructing the ServerT:

```
protectedServer :: AuthData -> ServerT ProtectedAPI Handler
protectedServer ad = enter (enterAuth ad) protectedServer'
```

where

```
genAuthServerContext :: Context (AuthHandler Request AuthData ': '[])
```